# How to Place admob Banner ads between data fetched from firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-redux, admob

I want to Show Banner Ads Between the Data which I have Fetched from FireBase, Here is my Code:

```
   showdata = imgs =>
    imgs.articles
      ? imgs.articles.map((item, i) => (
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.onPlay(item)} key={i}>
            <View style={styles.cardContainer}>
              <View style={styles.contentCard}>
                <Image
                  source={{uri: `${item.image}`}}
                  style={styles.imagestyle}
                  resizeMode="cover"
                />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.contentCard}>
                <Text style={styles.titleCard}>
                  {item.name}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        ))
      : null;
```

i want to place banner ads after every 3 cards.i am using Redux and firebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
customRenderRow = ({ item, index }) => {
   if (index !== 0 && index % 3 === 0) {
      return (
         <View>
           <AdmobBanner />

           ...card
         </View>
      );
   }
   return (
       ...card
   );
}
render () {
  return (
     <Flatlist
       ...
       renderItem={this.customRenderRow}
     />
  );
}
```